# Chartkick: How to pass parameters to the ChartsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I have created a ChartsController, for the async JSON loading.
It is decribed here: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#say-goodbye-to-timeouts

Everything works fine. But now I try to send a parameter to the controller how can this be done?

This is my call in the view.html.erb:

```
<%= line_chart test_charts_path %>
```

I want something like this:

```
<%= line_chart test_charts_path(object) %>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize you are just passing a link to the data in your `line_chart` that is the line chart will call the url to retrieve data.

So you can conveniently use route helpers like.

```
test_chart_path(param1: object)
```

and under your charts controller in test method

```
param1 = params[:param1] // whatever you pass comes here.
```